# In medieval era debates, was calling your opponent's source "Tamasic" a debating tactic?

Tags: puranas, sects

One reads about late medieval debates in which one side would cite Puranic material.  Are there instances when the opponents called it "Tamasic" to refute it?

Answer (score 5):

Sri Appayya Dikshita writes in his book, *Sivatattvaviveka*

> We are not very much worried about whether it is Vishnu or Siva who is
> the supreme deity spoken of by the Upanishads because we follow
> Advaita. But it is impossible for one like me to keep quiet when men
> with perverted minds proclaim in abusive language **their hatred toward
> Siva by calling these puranas as tamasic** — a hatred which consumes
> their hearts like flames. I have refuted these people but
> this does not mean that I am not a devotee of Vishnu

Comment: Also, there is a difference between 'Shiva'-dveshi and 'Shiva=Vishnu'-dveshi. When the 2nd is mistaken for the 1st, that is the main cause of intellectual friction between Shaivas/Vaishnavas. There is definitely an intersection between the two dveshi sets, but while the latter is sanctioned by Shastras, the former isn't afaik.

Comment: Beautiful answer ! I just hope there was someone like him who was in Krishna Bhakti. Madhusudhan ji was there but he didnt write commentary on Vedanta Sutra. Ayyappa Dikshita was also open hearted and perhabs only Vedantin to reject BS 1.3.38 and say any Sudra can achieve Non Dual Brahman

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Sir, please also remember Sri Appayya Dikshita wrote commentaries on advaita, vishisthaadvaita and dvaita but did not assert superiority of advaita over any of them. He said they were different paths leading to the same goal. In fact, he was also a follower of Vedanta Desika and did commentaries on his work. In fact, his commentaries on padusahasram and Yadavabhudaya are the only commentaries so far known. He wrote Hari-hara-stuti to show hari-hara-abheda by alternating epithets glorifying each.

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru His book, SiddhAnta lesa samgraha, points out the differences and similarities between the bhamati and vivarna schools of thought. He finally concludes that both of these sub schools are very similar and just mere semantics to talk about avidya. He agrees both of necessary depending on the aspirant but there is no right or wrong between these schools.

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Madhusudhan Sarasvati and Appayya Dikshita were born in same year (1520). The former wrote commentaries on Bhagavad Gita, Bhagavatam (partial) and dasa shloki. He wrote a word by word refutation of nyaya amrutha by the dualist school of vyasa tirtha. He was instrumental in getting tulsidas ram charit manas published. He tried to integrate vaishnavite faith in advaita, was the teacher of vallabhacharya's son and also initiated several non-brahmins as naga sadhus.

Comment: I know @GIRIBLR Sir that Madhusudhana Saraswathi ji did that. I even heard there were few non Brahmanas in Shankaracharya Mathas. I dont remember the name. Btw I didnt know he helped in publishing RCM. Sir I am just 19 yr old. Please dont call me sir. THanks a lot for the valuable information. I also like Vivekananda Swami believe all sects are true but Advaitha is final stage.

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Madhusudhana Sarasvati and Tulsidas were at the same time in Varanasi. As he was a great scholar on dvaita, nyaya and advaita, he was asked whether it should be allowed to publish ramayana in a local language. Due to the strong support of Madhusudhana, Tulsidas was able to publish his work.

Comment: @GIRIBLR Sir can we speak on Gmail,Hangouts or whaever platform you say so?I am deeply willing to become a sincere friend and learn from you!Please!I wont disturb you